# How to add multiple headers for http request using universal_io package [flutter web]

Tags: flutter, http-headers, httprequest, flutter-web

I would like to add multiple headers inside http request, I am using universal_io package because I build my project for flutter web. So far I have been doing this

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.badCertificateCallback =
          ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
      String url = 'http:....';
      Map map = {"email": "example@g.cc", "password": "password123ABC"};
      HttpClientRequest request =
          await client.putUrl(Uri.parse(url)).timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));
      ;
      if (request is BrowserHttpClientRequest) {
        request.credentialsMode = BrowserHttpClientCredentialsMode.automatic;
      }
      
      request.headers.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest'); // here, I would like to add one more header for "Authorization":"user token"

      request.add(utf8.encode(json.encode(map)));
      HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
      String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      final body = json.decode(reply);
```

is there a way to add one more header inside `request.headers.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');` ? because I would like to add `"Authorization":"user token"`

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method:

```dart
request.headers.add('authorization', 'user token');
```